# Prestashop webservice create order

Tags: php, xml, web-services, prestashop

I'm trying to create API connection to prestashop via webservices

I can create Custommers, Addresses, Carts succesfully
(there is available well known pure documentation about customers CRUD,
it works as expected)

I'm not able to complete new Order:

There is source code fragment

```
require_once('config.php'); // PS_SHOP_PATH etc.
require_once('PSWebServiceLibrary.php');

 try
 {
$webService = new PrestaShopWebservice(PS_SHOP_PATH, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY, DEBUG);
$opt = array('resource' => 'orders');
$xml = $webService->get(array('url' => PS_SHOP_PATH.'/api/orders?schema=blank'));

$xml->children()->children()->id_address_delivery = 1; 
$xml->children()->children()->id_address_invoice =  1; 
$xml->children()->children()->id_cart = 25; 
$xml->children()->children()->id_currency = 1;
$xml->children()->children()->current_state = 1;
$xml->children()->children()->id_lang = 1;
$xml->children()->children()->id_customer = 1; 
$xml->children()->children()->id_carrier = 0;
$xml->children()->children()->total_paid = '56973';
$xml->children()->children()->total_paid_real = '56973';
$xml->children()->children()->total_paid_tax_excl = '56973';
$xml->children()->children()->total_paid_tax_incl = '56977';
$xml->children()->children()->total_products = 1338;
$xml->children()->children()->total_products_wt = 1337;
$xml->children()->children()->conversion_rate = '1';
$xml->children()->children()->secure_key = md5('-1');;
$xml->children()->children()->valid = 1;
$xml->children()->children()->module = 'Bankwire';
$xml->children()->children()->payment = 'bankwire';
$xml->children()->children()->current_state = 1;

unset($xml->children()->children()->id);
unset($xml->children()->children()->date_add);
unset($xml->children()->children()->date_upd);
unset($xml->children()->children()->associations);
unset($xml->children()->children()->delivery_date);
unset($xml->children()->children()->invoice_date);
unset($xml->children()->children()->total_discounts_tax_incl);
unset($xml->children()->children()->total_discounts_tax_excl);


$xml = $webService->add(array('resource' => 'orders',
'postXml' => $xml->asXML()
));

$resources = $xml->children()->children();
echo "Successfully added order.".$resources->id;

}
catch (PrestaShopWebserviceException $ex)
{
    // Here we are dealing with errors
    $trace = $ex->getTrace();
    if ($trace[0]['args'][0] == 404) echo 'Bad ID';
    else if ($trace[0]['args'][0] == 401) echo 'Bad auth key';
    else echo 'Other error<br />'.$ex->getMessage();
}
```

And there is part. webview log from Fiddler

```
     XML SENT

   xml=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   <order>

    <id_address_delivery>1</id_address_delivery>
    <id_address_invoice>1</id_address_invoice>
    <id_cart>25</id_cart>
    <id_currency>1</id_currency>
    <id_lang>1</id_lang>
    <id_customer>1</id_customer>
    <id_carrier>0</id_carrier>
    <current_state>1</current_state>
    <module>Bankwire</module>
    <invoice_number/>

    <delivery_number/>

    <valid>1</valid>


    <id_shop_group/>
    <id_shop/>
    <secure_key>6bb61e3b7bce0931da574d19d1d82c88</secure_key>
    <payment>bankwire</payment>
    <recyclable/>
    <gift/>
    <gift_message/>
    <mobile_theme/>
    <total_discounts/>


    <total_paid>56973</total_paid>
    <total_paid_tax_incl>56977</total_paid_tax_incl>
    <total_paid_tax_excl>56973</total_paid_tax_excl>
    <total_paid_real>56973</total_paid_real>
    <total_products>1338</total_products>
    <total_products_wt>1337</total_products_wt>
    <total_shipping/>
    <total_shipping_tax_incl/>
    <total_shipping_tax_excl/>
    <carrier_tax_rate/>
    <total_wrapping/>
    <total_wrapping_tax_incl/>
    <total_wrapping_tax_excl/>
    <shipping_number/>
    <conversion_rate>1</conversion_rate>
    <reference/>

   </order>
   </prestashop>
```

RETURN HTTP BODY 
   Fatal error
   Other error

```
 HTTP XML response is not parsable : array ( 0 => LibXMLError::__set_state(array(     'level'    => 3, 'code' => 4, 'column' => 1, 'message' => 'Start tag expected, \'<\' not found ',     'file' => '', 'line' => 1, )), )
```

"Other error" comes from this:

```
  else echo 'Other error<br />'.$ex->getMessage();
```

PSWebServiceLibrary contains

```
/** @var array compatible versions of PrestaShop Webservice */
const psCompatibleVersionsMin = '1.4.0.17';
const psCompatibleVersionsMax = '1.5.4.1';
```

PrestaShop is 1.5.4.0

Any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Problem solved.**

1) create Customer (opt.)

2) create Address  (opt.)

3) check Products availibility (this is really better...)

4) create Cart with order_rows and with product id's and quantities

5) create Order with this

in all cases required tags should by filled- see /api/***object***?schema=synopsis

Simply cart should not be empty before create order, its sounds logic
in step by step intearctive process and the same sequence should
be done in "batch" processing via webservices.

Comment: 1.5.2.0 add Cart - status OK, bud only first Product proceed

Comment: 1.5.2.0 create Cart - status OK, bud only this first Product has been proceed and then creation of Order with this Cart ended with error; but Order is created ... only with first product; this is totaly unusable, because after creation of Order with erros  id_order IS NOT returned... wtf

Comment: 1.5.5.0 at the first should by manually changed major version in PSWebServiceLibrary.php - otherwise it does not work with this version; there are new required fields on product and creation of Cart ended with error intercept if they are filled i think best way i can do; new version -> new bugs, zero documentation

Comment: 1.5.6.1 works (first should by manually checked/changed major version in PSWebServiceLibrary.php) intercept sending info e-mails to customers (with a little bit hand coding)

Comment: could you please share the complete final source for creating an order?

Answer (score 1):

For placing order through webservice you need to make some entries directly to db with respect to cart like delivery option in cart table and for discount add entries in ps_cart_cart_rule table then place and order as you were placing.
1. add cart;
2. add discount options with respect to cart.
3. add delivery option with respect to cart.
4. Place order With same cart id.
Code as followed:

```
foreach ($raw_data['discounts'] as $discount) {
foreach ($raw_data['discounts'] as $discount) {
    $sql = "insert into ps_cart_cart_rule values('" . $id['cart'] . "','" . $discount['id_cart_rule'] . "')";
    $r = mysql_query($sql, $conn)or die(mysql_error($conn));
}

$sql = "update ps_cart set `delivery_option`='a:1:{i:" . $id['address'] . ";s:3:\"" . $id['carrier'] . ",\";}', `id_carrier`='" . $id['carrier'] . "' where id_cart='" . $id['cart'] . "'";
$r = mysql_query($sql, $conn)or die(mysql_error($conn));


$xml = $webService->get(array('url' => PS_SHOP_PATH . '/api/orders?schema=blank'));

$xml->order->id_customer = $id['customer'];
$xml->order->id_address_delivery = $id['address'];
$xml->order->id_address_invoice = $id['address'];
$xml->order->id_cart = $id['cart'];
$xml->order->id_currency = $id['currency'];
$xml->order->id_lang = $id['lang'];
$xml->order->id_carrier = $id['carrier'];
$xml->order->current_state = "3";
$xml->order->valid = 0;
$xml->order->total_shipping = $raw_data['total_shipping'];
$xml->order->total_shipping_tax_incl = $raw_data['total_shipping'];
$xml->order->total_shipping_tax_excl = $raw_data['total_shipping'];
$xml->order->total_discounts = $raw_data['total_discounts'];
$xml->order->total_discounts_tax_incl = $raw_data['total_discounts'];
$xml->order->total_discounts_tax_excl = $raw_data['total_discounts'];
$xml->order->payment = 'Cash on delivery';
$xml->order->module = 'cashondelivery';
$xml->order->total_products = $raw_data['total_products'];
$xml->order->total_products_wt = $raw_data['total_products'];
$xml->order->total_paid = $raw_data['total_paid'];
$xml->order->total_paid_tax_incl = $raw_data['total_paid'];
$xml->order->total_paid_tax_excl = $raw_data['total_paid'];
$xml->order->total_paid_real = "0";
$xml->order->conversion_rate = '1';
$opt = array('resource' => 'orders');
$opt['postXml'] = $xml->asXML();
$xml = $webService->add($opt);
$id['order'] = $xml->order->id;
$id['secure_key'] = $xml->order->secure_key;
```

Answer (score 0):

Following error is because of missing required value in **Cart** or **Order**

```
HTTP XML response is not parsable : array ( 0 => LibXMLError::__set_state(array(     'level'    => 3, 'code' => 4, 'column' => 1, 'message' => 'Start tag expected, \'<\' not found ',     'file' => '', 'line' => 1, )), )
```

In my case **id_address_delivery** & **id_address_invoice** where missing in Cart, that's why i was facing this error.

Read more at [PrestaShop web service create order errors](http://www.exploreroute.com/prestashop-webservice-create-order-errors/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this `Start tag expected, \'<\' not found ',` error try to check response which your sending to parse.
This is showing due to improper data that you sending in order or due to xml validation problem.

I also gone through same problem and I solved it by checking what response I am sending to parse method in Prestashop library.

Answer (score 0):

```
define('DEBUG', true);
define('PS_SHOP_PATH', 'http://.....');
define('PS_WS_AUTH_KEY', '...');
define('FILE_NAME', 'file.xlsx');
require_once('./PSWebServiceLibrary.php');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
require_once __DIR__.'/src/SimpleXLSX.php';

$newArray = array();  // here we will accumulate grouped data
$dataArray=[];
$product_count=0;
if ( $xlsx = SimpleXLSX::parse(FILE_NAME) ) {

    for($i=1; $i < count($xlsx->rows()); $i++){

        $id=$xlsx->rows()[$i][0];
        $product_id=$xlsx->rows()[$i][96];

        if($product_id)
        {
            if(!isset($dataArray[$id]))
            {
                $dataArray[$id]["products"][$product_id]= $xlsx->rows()[$i][103];
                $dataArray[$id]["price"]=$xlsx->rows()[$i][38];
                $dataArray[$id]["product_weight"]=$xlsx->rows()[$i][24];
                $dataArray[$id]["id_address_delivery"]=$xlsx->rows()[$i][170];
                $dataArray[$id]["id_carrier"]=$xlsx->rows()[$i][172];
                $dataArray[$id]["payment_mode"]=$xlsx->rows()[$i][173];
                $dataArray[$id]["product_count"]=$product_count;
                $dataArray[$id]["currency_code"] = $xlsx->rows()[$i][17];
            }
            else
            {
                if(!isset($dataArray[$id]["products"][$product_id]))
                {
                    $dataArray[$id]["products"][$product_id]+= $xlsx->rows()[$i][103];
                }
                else
                {
                    $dataArray[$id]["products"][$product_id]+= $xlsx->rows()[$i][103];
                }
            }
        }
    }

} else {
    echo SimpleXLSX::parseError();
}

try{

    foreach($dataArray as $key => $value){

        $webService = new PrestaShopWebservice(PS_SHOP_PATH, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY, DEBUG);
        $xml = $webService->get(array('url' => PS_SHOP_PATH.'/api/carts?schema=blank'));    

        $xml_currency = $webService->get(array('url' => PS_SHOP_PATH.'/api/currencies/?display=full'));
        $xml_language = $webService->get(array('url' => PS_SHOP_PATH.'/api/languages?display=full'));

        $value['id_language'] = (int)$xml_language->languages->language->id;

        $xml->cart->id_customer = $key;
        $count = 0;
        $value['total_products'] = 0;
        foreach($value['products'] as $product_key => $product_value){

            $xml->cart->associations->cart_rows->cart_row[$count]->id_product = $product_key;
            $xml->cart->associations->cart_rows->cart_row[$count]->quantity = $product_value;
            $value['total_products']+= $product_value; 
            $count++;   
        }

        for($i=0; $i<count($xml_currency->currencies->currency);$i++){
            if($xml_currency->currencies->currency[$i]->iso_code == $value['currency_code'])
                $value['id_currency'] =(int) $xml_currency->currencies->currency[$i]->id;
        }   

        $xml->cart->id_address_delivery = $value['id_address_delivery'];
        $xml->cart->id_address_invoice = $value['id_address_delivery'];
        $xml->cart->id_currency = $value['id_currency'];
        $xml->cart->id_lang = $value['id_language'];
        $xml->cart->id_carrier = $value['id_carrier'];

        $opt = array('resource' => 'carts');
        $opt['postXml'] = $xml->asXML();
        $xml = $webService->add($opt);
        $cart_id = $xml->cart->id;

        $xml = $webService->get(array('url' => PS_SHOP_PATH .'/api/orders/?schema=blank'));

        $xml->order->id_address_delivery = $value['id_address_delivery'];
        $xml->order->id_address_invoice  = $value['id_address_delivery'];
        $xml->order->id_cart = $cart_id;
        $xml->order->id_currency = $value['id_currency'];
        $xml->order->id_lang = $value['id_language'];
        $xml->order->id_customer = $key;
        $xml->order->id_carrier = $value['id_carrier'];
        if($value['payment_mode'] == 'Cash on delivery (COD)')
            $xml->order->module = 'ps_cashondelivery';
        if($value['payment_mode'] == 'Payment by check')
            $xml->order->module = 'ps_checkpayment';
        $xml->order->payment = $value['payment_mode'];
        $xml->order->total_paid = $value['price'];
        $xml->order->total_paid_real = $value['price'];
        $xml->order->total_products = $value['total_products'];
        $xml->order->total_products_wt = $value['product_weight'];
        $xml->order->conversion_rate = '1'; // conversion rate is fixed here

        $opt = array('resource' => 'orders');
        $opt['postXml'] = $xml->asXML();
        $xml = $webService->add($opt);
    }           

}catch (PrestaShopWebserviceException $e) {
// Here we are dealing with errors

    $trace = $e->getTrace();
    if ($trace[0]['args'][0] == 404) 
        echo 'Bad ID';
    else if ($trace[0]['args'][0] == 401) 
        echo 'Bad auth key';
    else 
        echo 'Other error<br />'.$e->getMessage();

} catch (PrestaShopWebserviceException $e) {

  // Here we are dealing with errors
  $trace = $e->getTrace();
  if ($trace[0]['args'][0] == 404) echo 'Bad ID';
  else if ($trace[0]['args'][0] == 401) echo 'Bad auth key';
  else echo 'Other error<br />'.$e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: id_address_delivery, id_address_invoice, id_carrier, payment_mode, Line: Product ID, Line: Quantity, Price: Total, Weight Total, id_address_delivery, id_carrier, payment_mode, Currency

These fields are there in the spreadsheet whose values gets retrived from on execution of the php code.Those fields are represented by column number. Its working fine and orders are getting created, provided you have customer id in the spreadsheet.

First carts are getting created based on customer id in the excell sheet and based on the cart id an order is getting created.